# Find() function in python

Tags: python, find

I just asked a question on stack overflow and this was the answer I got.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) == 0:
    fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
total = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    count = count + 1
    pos = line.find(' ')
    total = total + float(line[pos:])
average = total/count
print 'Average spam confidence:',average
```

I know how to use the find function but I don't understand how the answer was gotten. My problem is in line 10 and 11 of the code(the find and total line). Can someone please explain it to me. Thanks.

Comment: Is your question about `find` or slicing `line[pos:]`?

Comment: Thanks guys. I know get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pos = line.find(' ')
```

This line means in the `line`, `pos` will be first occurnece of `space` .

```
total = total + float(line[pos:])
```

and this line means after `space` comes a string that should be cast to `float` and it should be added to total :

for example if line would be this :

```
X-DSPAM-Confidence: 4.23232
```

then `pos` will be 19 (position of space) and `line[pos:]`(from space to end of string) is `"4.23232"` then you cast it to `float` that means `total = total + 4.23232`

Comment: Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people
experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed. For more
information, take a look at our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks and welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the format of the input, but I can image it's something like this:
"texte 123.33"

So, line.find(" ") is use to find the first space.
After that, line[pos:] extract the part after the space, and the float convert this part to a float number to add to the total.
A better way to do this in one line (and not two) should be :

```
total = total + float(line.split(" ")[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`line.find(' ')` Return the lowest index in `line` where the substring `" "` is found.

`line[pos:]` will try to get a sub string from line starting from `pos`. (Slicing Python strings).

Check  [Python strings](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)